# Rails: Displaying state_machine validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, error-handling, state-machine

I'm using [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) for an online purchasing process in Ruby on Rails. One of the states consists of the user filling in a form with billing information. This form is required, so I'm validating it when transitioning to the next state like so:

```
state :confirm do
  validates_presence_of :name, :email
end
```

Where the form is on state `:info` and the next one is `:confirm`.

This works fine: If any fields are missing state_machine will not transition to the next state.
However I can't find information on how to display an error notification when the validation returns false. I want to display a message when this validation fails, and redirects to the form state. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Assuming what you mean is adding something like <%= current_order.errors if current_order.errors.present? %> to my view, I tried that and it shows no errors :( If you meant something else I'm sorry I understood you wrong! Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

*(I assume you have solved this long ago, but...)*
I think this answer has nothing to do with state_machine. This is the problem:

> I want to display a message when this validation fails, and **redirects** to the form state.

If you **redirect**, the object is reloaded and all the unsaved attributes are lost, as are any validation errors.

Standard way to handle failed validation is to (re-)**render** the edit view, not redirect to the edit action.  This retains the unsaved attributes and validation errors.